# How to HyperlinkedRelatedField into a model from different app?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

bellow is `urls.py` of `users` app.

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
]
```

url conf of `snippets` app:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'snippets'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SnippetList.as_view(), name='snippet-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.SnippetDetail.as_view(), name='snippet-detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/highlight/', views.SnippetHighlight.as_view(), name='snippet-highlight'),
]
```

and here's `SnippetSerializer`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from . import models


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Snippet
        fields = ['id', 'owner', 'title', 'code', 'highlight', 'linenos', 'language', 'style']

    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippets:snippet-highlight', format='html')
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        view_name='users:user-detail'
    )
```

The error I got

> ImproperlyConfigured at /snippets/
> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "users:user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I specified `id` instead of `pk` in url pattern of `users` app.
Such things make me feel frustrated.